# HTML/CSS Tic Tac Toe board: cells are moving around while they shouldn't

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML/CSS/JavaScript and I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game in the browser. I thought I had the board set up, but noticed that the cells are changing position as soon as I remove one or more X/O tokens. I can't figure out what causes this bug and  would really appreciate help.

```css
.board {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 70px auto;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 2px 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="board">
  <h2>Player X's turn</h2>
  <div class="row0">
    <div class="cell c00">X</div>
    <div class="cell c01">O</div>
    <div class="cell c02">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="cell c10">O</div>
    <div class="cell c11">X</div>
    <div class="cell c12">O</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="cell c20">X</div>
    <div class="cell c21">O</div>
    <div class="cell c22">X</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: It's not a bug it's how flexbox works. Stack of elements on one axis. For a grid like layout you may want to check css grid

Comment: Use css grid for this.

Comment: CSS grid fixed it indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well it is because you are using inline-flex, which makes the div inline positiond and relative to the content it has, you can try to change the font-size and see how it affects all divs. I am not sure why you are trying to use inline flex but I would recommend you to read this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) I personally would just set the .row0, .row1 and .row2 to just display: flex and tweek the width of the .board a little

```css
.board {
    display: block;
    width: 326px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 70px auto;

}

.cell {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 2px 0;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 100px;
}
.row0, .row1, .row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
   <section class="board">
            <h2>Player X's turn</h2>
            <div class="row0">
                <div class="cell c00">X</div>
                <div class="cell c01">O</div>
                <div class="cell c02"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                <div class="cell c10">O</div>
                <div class="cell c11">X</div>
                <div class="cell c12">O</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row2">
                <div class="cell c20">X</div>
                <div class="cell c21"></div>
                <div class="cell c22">X</div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently it can also be fixed using CSS grid.